# Use MAX(Date) value inside a SQL recursion

Tags: sql-server

I have SQL query with performs recursion based on selected Min(Date) and Max(Date) from more than 1 table. But when i try to run the query it throws `GROUP BY, HAVING, or aggregate functions are not allowed in the recursive part of a recursive common table expression 'ctedaterange'.` exception. I also tried using Top 1 Date but still no hope.

**SQL Query**

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[CYExtraction]
AS

WITH ctedaterange
AS (SELECT
    [Dates] = (SELECT
    MIN(CreatedOn) AS CreatedOn
    FROM (SELECT
    MIN(CreatedOn) AS CreatedOn
    FROM (SELECT
    MIN(CreatedOn) AS CreatedOn
    FROM Items) AS it
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    *
    FROM (SELECT
    MIN(CreatedOn) AS CreatedOn
    FROM Bibs) AS bib
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    *
    FROM (SELECT
    MIN(CreatedOn) AS CreatedOn
    FROM Porders) AS po) AS AllItems)
UNION ALL
SELECT
    [dates] + 1
FROM ctedaterange
WHERE [dates] + 1 <= (SELECT
    MAX(CreatedOn) AS CreatedOn
FROM (SELECT
    MAX(CreatedOn) AS CreatedOn
FROM (SELECT
    MAX(CreatedOn) AS CreatedOn
FROM Items) AS it
UNION ALL
SELECT
    *
FROM (SELECT
    MAX(CreatedOn) AS CreatedOn
FROM Bibs) AS bib
UNION ALL
SELECT
    *
FROM (SELECT
    MAX(CreatedOn) AS CreatedOn
FROM Porders) AS po) AS AllItems))
SELECT
    [Dates] AS PK_Date,
    DATENAME(MONTH, [Dates]) + ' ' + CAST(YEAR([Dates]) AS varchar(4)) AS 
Month,
    CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(m, [Dates]) <= 3 THEN 'Q1 ' + CAST(YEAR([Dates]) AS varchar(4))
        ELSE CASE
            WHEN DATEPART(m, [Dates]) <= 6 THEN 'Q2 ' + CAST(YEAR([Dates]) AS varchar(4))
        ELSE CASE
            WHEN DATEPART(m, [Dates]) <= 9 THEN 'Q3 ' + CAST(YEAR([Dates]) AS varchar(4))
            ELSE CASE
                WHEN DATEPART(m, [Dates]) <= 12 THEN 'Q4 ' + CAST(YEAR([Dates]) AS varchar(4))
                ELSE ''
            END
        END
    END
END AS 'Quarter',
CASE
    WHEN DATEPART(m, [Dates]) <= 6 THEN 'HY1 ' + CAST(YEAR([Dates]) AS varchar(4))
    ELSE CASE
        WHEN DATEPART(m, [Dates]) <= 12 THEN 'HY2  ' + CAST(YEAR([Dates]) AS varchar(4))
        ELSE ''
    END
END AS 'HalfYear',
YEAR([Dates]) AS 'Year',
CAST('1-' AS varchar(5)) + CAST(DATEPART(M, [Dates]) AS varchar(10)) + '-' + CAST(YEAR([Dates]) AS varchar(4)) AS DateName
FROM ctedaterange


GO
```

The main thing is that I need to wrap it inside my SQL Views. Any help to my problem will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Why did you select the MIN of a MIN of a MIN?   What do you think that is accomplishing?   I would bet that's probably the first of many errors in this query.   It's hard to infer your intentions from your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can move the aggregations to an extra cte, so this might be what you want:

```
ALTER VIEW [dbo].[CYExtraction] 
  (PK_Date, [Month], [Quarter], [HalfYear], [Year], [DateName])
AS
WITH cteAllItems (mindates, maxdates) AS (
  SELECT MIN(CreatedOn), MAX(CreatedOn) FROM Items
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MIN(CreatedOn), MAX(CreatedOn) FROM Bibs
  UNION ALL
  SELECT MIN(CreatedOn), MAX(CreatedOn) FROM Porders
),
   ctedaterange (Dates, MaxDate) AS (
  SELECT MIN(mindates), MAX(maxdates) 
  FROM cteAllItems
  UNION ALL
  SELECT DATEADD(day, 1, Dates), MaxDate 
  FROM ctedaterange
  WHERE DATEADD(day, 1, Dates) <= MaxDate
)
SELECT
  Dates AS PK_Date,
  DATENAME(MONTH, Dates) + N' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, Dates),
  N'Q' + DATENAME(QUARTER, Dates) + N' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, Dates),
  N'HY' + CAST((MONTH(Dates)-1)/6+1 AS nvarchar(1)) + N' ' + DATENAME(YEAR, Dates),
  YEAR(Dates),
  CONVERT(nvarchar(10), DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, Dates), 0), 105)
FROM ctedaterange

GO
```